# use tee to save log file in a subfolder (defined in a variable)

Tags: bash, log, tee

The input file of a script is passed as an argument from command line. I want the log file from tee to be saved in the same directory than the input file:

Lets say that input file is at "data/temp/inputfile.txt"

This is the part that is giving me problems:

```
{
INPUT1=$1

#Save each subdirectory as an element of the array
bkpIFS="$IFS"
IFS='/' read -r -a inputstring <<< $INPUT1
IFS="$bkpIFS"

#Get number of levels
PATHLENGTH=${#inputstring[@]}

if [ PATHLENGTH > 1 ]
then
    #Delete the input file from path
    FILEONLY=${inputstring[-1]}
    INPUTFOLDER=${INPUT1/%$FILEONLY/}
    #Name the log file
    LOGFILE="arrays.log"
    LOGPATH="$INPUTFOLDER$LOGFILE"
else
    #If input file is at working directory
    LOGPATH="arrays.log"
fi

# Here goes the main script...

printf "\nDone!\n"

}  | tee $LOGPATH
```

I'm just getting an empty file named "1" at the working directory. Of course if I write in the last line:

```
} | tee arrays.log
```

everything goes well, but I need each log file in the same place than the input file.

Comment: Why don't you use a shell function? `my_function(){INPUT="$1" …}; my_function | tee "$LOGPATH"`

Comment: Thanks, using dirname to define $LOGPATH worked just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks overly complicated.

```
LOGPATH=$(dirname $1)/arrays.log
```

should do the same thing, even in the case where there is no directory in $1 (because `$dirname foobar` returns `.`).

Comment: You are right, it was, basically because I'm not used to unix yet. thanks. That worked just right